# How to find square root of large numbers in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find out the square root of a number. But the numbers are large. Python gives the error

> OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

My code is here:

```
number=pow(255,200)-10000000
sqrt=math.sqrt(number)
```

i tried it with the decimal class but it doesn't work.
How to handle these large numbers in python?

Comment: the Decimal class it can handle it with its `.sqrt` method: `(pow(Decimal(255),200)-10000000).sqrt()` = `Decimal('4.508354347658170012443202806E+240')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
pow(10, 1/2 * math.log10(pow(255,200)-10000000))
```

The result is: 4.508354347658245e+240

Comment: Its working fine but it cannot assign to a variable.